# Scrapy does not execute requests in order of priority values

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website where state is encoded in the current session cookie, which means that I need to follow links in an exactly given order. Otherwise, the results will be different.

I am trying to scrape this website with the `priority` setting of scrapy, but it seems scrapy does not follow the priority in case it already pulls some pages into a request queue buffer or similar. This is the minimum example I came up with:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class DebugSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "debug"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,  # just to remove some debug messages
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(4):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                'https://example.com/',
                dont_filter=True,
                callback=self.parse_low_prio,
                priority=0)

    def parse_low_prio(self, response):
        print('Crawled example.com (low prio)')

        return [scrapy.Request(
            'https://example.org/',
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.parse_high_prio,
            priority=1)]

    def parse_high_prio(self, response):
        print('Crawled example.org (high prio)')

        return None
```

My expected result would be that scrapy crawls the websites in the following order:

- low prio (after this it yields the first request with a high prio and should immediately request the high prio)
- high prio (only one high prio request so far, so next it can continue with low prio)
- low prio
- high prio
- ...

Instead in reality they seem to be somewhat delayed, because scrapy executes two low prio requests.

```
2019-12-22 12:19:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
Crawled example.com (low prio)
2019-12-22 12:19:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
2019-12-22 12:19:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.com (low prio)
Crawled example.org (high prio)
2019-12-22 12:19:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.org (high prio)
2019-12-22 12:19:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
Crawled example.com (low prio)
2019-12-22 12:19:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.org (high prio)
2019-12-22 12:19:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
Crawled example.com (low prio)
2019-12-22 12:19:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.org (high prio)
```

The order of execution is not 100% deterministic either.

What confuses me even more is the behaviour when I exchange the priorities:

```
def start_requests(self):
    requests = []
    for i in range(4):
        requests.append(scrapy.Request(
            'https://example.com/',
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.parse_low_prio,
            priority=1))

    return requests

def parse_low_prio(self, response):
    print('Crawled example.com (new high prio)')

    return [scrapy.Request(
        'https://example.org/',
        dont_filter=True,
        callback=self.parse_high_prio,
        priority=0)]

def parse_high_prio(self, response):
    print('Crawled example.org (new low prio)')

    return None
```

Now one would expect that scrapy already knows all high priority requests and would for sure execute them in the right order. Instead, I am again getting the same weird behaviour:

```
2019-12-22 12:28:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
Crawled example.com (new high prio)
2019-12-22 12:28:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
Crawled example.com (new high prio)
2019-12-22 12:28:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.org (new low prio)
2019-12-22 12:28:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
Crawled example.com (new high prio)
2019-12-22 12:28:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.org (new low prio)
2019-12-22 12:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/> (referer: None)
Crawled example.com (new high prio)
2019-12-22 12:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.org (new low prio)
2019-12-22 12:28:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org/> (referer: https://example.com/)
Crawled example.org (new low prio)
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to enable a PriorityMiddleware somewhere? I am executing my spider with `scrapy runspider debugspider.py` in an empty folder with a fresh virtual environment with scrapy 1.8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy is asynchronous framework.
I will try to explain what happend in your case:

1. Result of `start_requests` method from your spider added 4 requests.

    1 request immediately transferred to scrapy `downloader` for execution as it configured by `custom_settings` attribute of your spider. 
    remaining 3 requests - (on hold) transferred to scrapy `scheduler` queue
2. When scrapy received response from that first request Scrapy`downloader` became "free" (active requests < `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`) And it asks next request from `scheduler`. 
    This happening BEFORE `parse_low_prio` spider method was called. At this moment scrapy application don't know anything about high priority requests as it don't have results from `parse_low_prio` method.
   And scrapy `scheduler` contain only 3 remaining requests from `start_requests` - as result one of them transferred to `downloader` for execution. -- As result first 2 requests - low_priority requests.
3. When second request sent, 
    Scrapy `downloader` became "busy" (downloader active requests = `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`). And only after that first callback function (`parse_low_prio`) is starting to execute.

One of possible solutions to receive required sequence of requests/callback.:

```
def start_requests(self):
    self.queries = [.....]
    next_url = self.queries.pop(0) #schedule only first query request
    yield scrapy.Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse_low_prio,
                         priority=0, dont_filter=True)

def parse_low_prio(self, response):
    print('Crawled example.com (low prio)')

    yield scrapy.Request(url='https://example.org/', callback=self.parse_high_prio,
                         priority=0 , dont_filter=True)

def parse_high_prio(self, response):
    print('Crawled example.org (high prio)')
    #scheduling next query request
    next_url = self.queries.pop(0) # next request
    if next_url:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse_low_prio,
                         priority=0, dont_filter=True)
```